# Error evaluationScheme recommenderlab in R

Tags: r

I am newbie in R, actually I have mining movielens-M data to provide recommendation system, but when I run my code following below, I faced some error like this:

```
> ##read the rating data for all users
> readData<-function(){
+   ratingDF <- read.delim("ratings.dat", sep=':',header=F)
+   ratingDF <- subset(ratingDF, select = c("V1","V3","V5","V7"))
+   names(ratingDF) <- c("userID","movieID","rating","timestamp")
+   
+   moviesDF <- readLines("movies.dat")
+   moviesDF <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind",strsplit(moviesDF,"::")),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+   names(moviesDF) <- c("movieID","Title","Genre")
+   
+   return(list(ratingDF=ratingDF, movieDF=moviesDF))
+ }
> 
> 
> ##data cleansing and processing
> preProcess= function(ratingDF,moviesDF){
+   
+   ratingDF[,2] <- dataList$movieDF$Title[as.numeric(ratingDF[,2])]
+   #remove duplicate 
+   ratingDF <- ratingDF[!duplicated(ratingDF[,1:2]),]
+ }
> 
> 
> createRatingMatrix <- function(ratingDF){
+   
+   #converting the ratingData data frame into rating matrix
+   ratingDF_tmp <- dcast(ratingDF, userID ~ movieID, value.var = "rating", index ="userID")
+   ratingDF <- ratingDF_tmp[,2:ncol(ratingDF_tmp)]
+   
+   ratingMat<-as(ratingDF,"matrix")
+   movieRatingMat<-as(ratingMat,"realRatingMatrix")
+   
+   #setting up the dimnames
+   dimnames(movieRatingMat)[[1]]<-row.names(ratingDF)
+   return(movieRatingMat)
+   
+ }
> 
> #create recommender model
> evaluateModels<-function(movieRatingMat){
+   
+   #find out and anlyze available recommendation algorithm option for realRatingMatrix data
+   recommenderRegistry$get_entries(dataType="realRatingMatrix")
+   scheme <- evaluationScheme(movieRatingMat, method="split", train=.9, k=1, given=10, goodRating=4)
+   algorithms<-list(
+     RANDOM = list(name="RANDOM", param=NULL),
+     POPULAR = list(name="POPULAR", param=NULL),
+     UBCF = list(name="UBCF", param=NULL), 
+     IBCF = list(name="IBCF", param=NULL)
+   )
+   
+   #run algorithms, predict next n movie
+   results<-evaluate(scheme, algorithms, n=c(1,3,5,10,15,20))
+   
+   #select the first results
+   return(results)
+   
+ }
>   
>   
> ##load movie lens data
> dataList<-readData()
> 
> ratingDF<-preProcess(dataList$ratingDF, dataList$movieDF)
> 
> 
> movieRatingMat<-createRatingMatrix(ratingDF)
> 
> evalList<-evaluateModels(movieRatingMat)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in .local(data, ...) : Some observations have size<given! 
>
```

In here, I have known the problem, it is because `given` parameter, but I dont know why it can happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recommender lab, `given` parameter is single number of items given for evaluation or a vector of length of data giving the number of items given for each observation. So why you faced an error is because the vector size of your data is less that the vector of given size.

Comment: you mean.. given should be size of `movieRatingMat` ? can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

@Kavipriya: Some of your users in your `movieRatingMat` matrix (that is some rows) might have ratings for less than 10 movies say 4 or 6, and in that case, you are asking `recommenderlab` to use 10 ratings anyways which it can't use because they are missing right. The workaround is to use a lower value for `given =` or input that matrix which has a sufficient number of ratings for every user. In case you don't know maths behind it: package calculates the distance between 2 vectors and both the vectors need to be of the same length. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've also seen given used with a negative number. What does that mean? Is it safe to keep given at 1? What are the trade-offs (overfitting?)